# Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "BY" at position 68) and Unrecognized alter operation. (near "BY" at position 68)

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YourRootPassword';
-- then
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: [ALTER USER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html). Don't try to invent your own syntax - the server won't understand it anyway.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having in more detail rather than posting an error messages and unexplained SQL.